# Node server stops when monitoried via monit

Tags: node.js, monit

I am trying to monitor a simple helloworld script running in a node server. The applicaion works fine left alone.  But when I used monit to monitor, I can see that the node server stops and is repeatedly restarted by monit everytime.

Can someone please help me?

## hello-world.js

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      res.end('Hello, World!\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
      console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

## monit.log

```
WIB Jun  9 14:51:07] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed protocol test [HTTP] at [localhost]:3000 [TCP/IP] -- Connection refused
[WIB Jun  9 14:51:07] info     : 'selva-dev1' trying to restart
[WIB Jun  9 14:51:07] info     : 'selva-dev1' start: '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/hello-world.js'


[WIB Jun  9 14:52:07] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed to start (exit status -1) -- '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/hello-world.js': Program timed out -- Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/

[WIB Jun  9 14:52:22] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed protocol test [HTTP] at [localhost]:3000 [TCP/IP] -- Connection refused
[WIB Jun  9 14:52:22] info     : 'selva-dev1' trying to restart
[WIB Jun  9 14:52:22] info     : 'selva-dev1' start: '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/hello-world.js'
[WIB Jun  9 14:53:23] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed to start (exit status -1) -- '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/hello-world.js': Program timed out -- Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/

[WIB Jun  9 14:53:38] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed protocol test [HTTP] at [localhost]:3000 [TCP/IP] -- Connection refused
[WIB Jun  9 14:53:38] info     : 'selva-dev1' trying to restart
[WIB Jun  9 14:53:38] info     : 'selva-dev1' start: '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/hello-world.js'
[WIB Jun  9 14:54:38] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed to start (exit status -1) -- '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/hello-world.js': Program timed out -- Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

## monitrc

```
check host selva-dev1 with address localhost
start program = "/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/hello-world.js " with timeout 60 seconds
if failed port 3000 with protocol http with timeout 15 seconds then restart
```

## UPDATE

Based on the suggestion from siebteman and Marc,  I tried another script which  does not involve hostname resolution

## uppercase.js

```
var http = require('http');
var uc = require('upper-case');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      /*Use our upper-case module to upper case a string:*/
      res.write(uc.upperCase("Hello World!"));
      res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Still the Node server keeps crashing.  Which is why monit is trying to restart it every time.

```
[WIB Jun  9 15:53:54] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed to start (exit status -1) -- Program '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/uppercase.js' timed out after 1 m
[WIB Jun  9 15:54:09] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed protocol test [HTTP] at [selva-dev]:8080 [TCP/IP] -- Connection refused
[WIB Jun  9 15:54:09] info     : 'selva-dev1' trying to restart
[WIB Jun  9 15:54:09] info     : 'selva-dev1' start: '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/uppercase.js'
[WIB Jun  9 15:55:09] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed to start (exit status -1) -- Program '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/uppercase.js' timed out after 1 m
[WIB Jun  9 15:55:24] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed protocol test [HTTP] at [selva-dev]:8080 [TCP/IP] -- Connection refused
[WIB Jun  9 15:55:24] info     : 'selva-dev1' trying to restart
[WIB Jun  9 15:55:24] info     : 'selva-dev1' start: '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/uppercase.js'
[WIB Jun  9 15:56:24] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed to start (exit status -1) -- Program '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/uppercase.js' timed out after 1 m
[WIB Jun  9 15:56:39] error    : 'selva-dev1' failed protocol test [HTTP] at [selva-dev]:8080 [TCP/IP] -- Connection refused
[WIB Jun  9 15:56:39] info     : 'selva-dev1' trying to restart
[WIB Jun  9 15:56:39] info     : 'selva-dev1' start: '/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/uppercase.js'
```

## monitrc

```
check host selva-dev1 with address selva-dev
start program = "/usr/bin/node /home/selva/tools/testnode/uppercase.js"  with timeout 60 seconds
if failed port 8080 with protocol http with timeout 15 seconds then restart
```

Comment: Try changing `localhost` in your monitrc to `127.0.0.1`. It is possible that monit is connecting directly to the loopback device without going through the entire TCP/IP stack and thus is not connecting to `127.0.0.1`. Also, generally it is **not normal** to start a node server (or any other HTTP server for that matter like Jakarta or Nginx etc.) with a host address binding configured. Delete the `hostname` part of the code in node.js unless you really don't want your node server visible from anywhere else

Comment: @siebteman He should set the "hostname" var to "0.0.0.0". So he listen at all interfaces. (If this is wanted). Otherwise its absolut ok to bind a socket/start a webserver on a specific interface.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  But it looks like it is beyond resolving hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

Monit can handle Node scripts, but you should start the Node script in a new process.

```
check host Helloworld with address localhost
  start program "/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/lutz/node/helloworld.js >/dev/null 2>&1 &'" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program "/bin/bash -c 'pkill -TERM helloworld.js'"
  if failed port 3000 with protocol http with timeout 15 seconds then restart
```

Node does not switch to a new process itself.